# Dynamic php form

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to get my login form to change based on if the user is 'new' or 'existing'. For example if 'existing user' selected only display 'username', and 'password' input fields. While choosing  'new user' would get you 'username','email','password', and 'passwordconfirm'.

```
<select id="login_type" name="logintype">
 <option value="Register">a new user</option> 
 <option value="Login">an existing user</option>
</select>
```

Tried the code below but it got stuck when it read my html form inside my if else. What can I do to?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login_type']) && $_POST['login_type'] == 'an existing user') 
{ 
<div>
    <label for="uname_input">Username:</label>
    <input id="uname_input" name="uname" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Enter your username"/>
    <br />
    <label for="pass_input">Password:</label>
    <input id="pass_input" name="passwd" type="password" required="required" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
</div> 

<input id="submit_login" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 

} 
else 
{ 
    <div class="shownew">
        <label for="em_input">Email:</label>
        <input id="em_input" name="email" type="text"  placeholder="Enter a valid email address"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="uname_input">Username:</label>
        <input id="uname_input" name="uname" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Enter your username"/>
        <br />
        <label for="pass_input">Password:</label>
        <input id="pass_input" name="passwd" type="password" required="required" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="shownew">
        <label for="pass2_input">Confirm:</label>
        <input id="pass2_input" name="passwd2" type="password" placeholder="Repeat your password"/>
    </div> 
    <input id="submit_login" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}

if (isset($_GET['error']))
{
  $errmsg = '';
  switch ($_GET['error'])
  {
  case 1: $errmsg = 'Passwords entered do not match one another.'; break;
  case 2: $errmsg = 'Username already exists in the database. Please choose   a           different username.'; break;
  case 3: $errmsg = 'The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.'; break;
  case 4: $errmsg = 'Invalid login mode. Please reload the page and try again.'; break;
  case 5: $errmsg = 'Unexpected error processing login. Please try again'; break;
  default: $errmsg = 'An unknown error occurred. Please try again in a few minutes.'; break;
  }
  print '<p class="errmsg">' . $errmsg . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not echoing anything

Comment: It must be `$_POST['logintype']` instead of `$_POST['login_type']` (name is crucial) as well as `Register` or `Login` instead of `a new user` or `an existing user`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have missing php opening / closing tags :

```
if (isset($_POST['login_type']) && $_POST['login_type'] == 'an existing user') 
{ 
<div>
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['login_type']) && $_POST['login_type'] == 'an existing user') 
{
?> 
<div>
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The select name is 'logintype' and forgot to close ) in isset

Change

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login_type']) && $_POST['login_type'] == 'an existing user') 
{
```

to

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['logintype']) && $_POST['logintype'] == 'an existing user') 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="login_type" name="logintype">
  <option value="Register">a new user</option> 
  <option value="Login">an existing user</option>
</select>
```

logintype is either `Register` or `Login`. The description has nothing to do here.